# UITableView swiping to delete - aligning text labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I have a regular `UITableViewCell` and when I swipe it left it reveals a Delete button.

However the table view looks like this:
[image]

What I would like to have here is to have the `textLabel`s aligned all the time, not going out of the screen when swiped.

Can this be done using regular UITableViewCells? I thought about observing `cell.contentView`'s frame changes and moving the labels accordingly (the red-framed on the screenshot are `cell.contentView`s), but those seem to have the origin at `{0,0}` all the time.

Should I get my own custom class to get this effect?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use UITableViewCell's setEditing method and adjust the frame or constraints. Here's how to do it if the label has a leading constraint -

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    NSInteger leadingSpace = 10;
    NSInteger editingOffset = 82;
    if (editing) {
        self.labelLeadingContraint.constant = leadingSpace + editingOffset;
    } else {
        self.labelLeadingContraint.constant = leadingSpace;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```